# Possible to use ActionScript 3 without Adobe Flash Professional?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I don't have Adobe Flash Professional, but I would like to use ActionScript 3. Is there a way to create Flash .swf files for games with ActionScript without Adobe Flash?

Is there any software that I can use that not cost any? Freeware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) built on [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), or [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Apps or libraries can be built with the [MXMLC compiler from the Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html), which can be installed to Eclipse as a plugin.

There are also projects such as [Haxe](http://haxe.org), which can compile to the Flash runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess there is no freeware that both where I can use ActionScript3 and use the graphics that I have inside Flash?

Comment: Nothing that's exactly like authoring on Flash Pro's artboard.  You can export your graphics from Flash Pro as a SWC to include in pure ActionScript projects.  Any option with the Flex SDK or HaXe is free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for example, [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/). You will lose the entire graphical design interface, but will receive a better code editor, better debugger and will have a little better control over what's going on in your project, by eradicating main timeline.